# Create a form by parsing yaml file

Tags: django, wtforms, flask-wtforms, pyyaml

I have a yaml file as follows

```
name:
    property_type: string
    mandatory: True
    default: None
    help: your full name

address:
    city:
        property_type: string
        mandatory: True
        default: None
        help: city

    state:
        property_type: string
        mandatory: True
        default: None
        help: state
```

What i want to do is that parse this file to create a form class (which could be used by Django or WT-Forms) to create web forms.

I cannot simply make the class because the the form (and hence the class) needs to update automatically whenever the yaml config file is updated.

I am currently trying to use pyyaml to accomplish this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I have no sucess. I am just able to parse the yaml file to get the data but have no idea how to create a class using the data.

Comment: Django forms are nothing more than standard Python classes. You need to add the fields from the data by overriding the `__init__()` of the form and creating instances of the fields based on the values.

Comment: but then how will the init automatically update? For eg. if i add a field 'Country', then i'll have to update the init manually?

Comment: You're not going to be able to dynamically add columns to a table without a schema migration if that's what you're asking, but no, you shouldn't have to update the init every time, provided you're catching all of the property_types you need.

Comment: schema migration? we don't have a database in the picture?

Comment: Well you didn't specifically mention how, of if you wanted to persist this data, which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: i don't need to save the data in a database, i just need to process the data and give the output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is pass in the data to the form class and override the `__init__` to add the fields you need:

```
# PSEUDO CODE - don't just copy and paste this

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.field_data = kwargs.pop('field_data')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # assuming a list of dictionaries here...
        for field in field_data:
            if field['property_type'] == 'string':
                self.fields[field['name']] = forms.CharField(
                    max_length=field['max_length'], help_text=field['help'],
                    required=field['mandatory'], initial=field['default'])
            elif field['property_type'] == 'something else':
                # add another type of field here


# example use in a view
def my_view(request):
    field_data = parse_yaml('some-file.yml')
    form = MyForm(field_data=field_data)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()  # you need to write this method

    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'form': form})
```

as long as you're checking for the appropriate "property_type", you shouldn't need to update your form class. If you add a new field to the yaml, the form will reflect the field.

Comment: I'd love to know why this was downvoted. If you have a better way of doing this, by all means, enlighten us.